# A tense problem about an auto reply model

Tags: tense

I want to set an auto reply model when I'm holding an online chat room and dealing with some other things.
Which of the following is correct:

1. If I didn't say hi, it means I am working.
2. If I haven't said hi, it means I am working.
3. If I don't say hi, it means I am working.

Comment: All of these are grammatically correct; though I've seen #3 the most often, I think it's just because it is the shortest one to say (by one syllable). All of them sound natural.

Comment: I vote for #3. You might reply *after* the auto-reply does.